# Delete files in Folder Recursively in JAVA I/O

Tags: java, recursion, directory, io

In Java/Unix I understand you can't delete a folder with something in it and I can do it without recursion but this simple solution is great but I just can't see where/when this is deleting the actual files? by using the delete() function. I clearly see it using the delete() on the actual folder at the end but I don't see how it is or when it is calling delete() on the files it just gets them and when I feel it should be calling delete() it makes the recursive call???

I know it is something simple I am missing but it is driving me crazy and no where can I find answer any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
boolean deleteDirectory(File directoryToBeDeleted) {
    File[] allContents = directoryToBeDeleted.listFiles();
    if (allContents != null) {
        for (File file : allContents) {
            deleteDirectory(file);
        }
    }
    return directoryToBeDeleted.delete();
}
```

Comment: The last line deletes files, and also empty directories. Perhaps the argument name is misleading. It should perhaps be `directoryOrFileToBeDeleted`. If `listFiles()` returns null then the argument is actually a file and not a directory.

Comment: return directoryToBeDeleted.delete(); this line? This is deleting the directory I thought?  It calls deleteDirectory(file) with one of the files but each time it just calls deleteDirectory(file) again when does it actually delete each individual files?

Comment: As I explained, `directoryToBeDeleted` is not always a directory, it can also be a file. And when it's a file it gets deleted by that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`directoryToBeDeleted` is not always a directory. If `allContents == null` then `directoryToBeDeleted` is a file, not a directory as `.listFiles()` returns null if the object of type `File` is a file and not a folder.

Comment: I thought the whole point of the recursion was to delete the files inside the folder.  Assume for a minute there are files inside. 1 folder 5000 files.  When is it deleting those individual files? I understand the last line, that's when it deletes the empty folder but in the recursive call it is just calling the  call with a file. That would seem to work but it returns directoryToBeDeleted(). I still don't see when the 5000 files gets deleted?

Comment: Let's follow your example. 1 folder (we'll call it `x`), 5000 files. 
We run `deleteDirectory(x)`. 
`File[] allContents = directoryToBeDeleted.listFiles();` becomes an array of 5000 files. Therefore it is not null, so for each of those 5000 files we can call `deleteDirectory(file);`. This is your recursive call. This time because they are files and not folders `File[] allContents = directoryToBeDeleted.listFiles();` will be null for each of them (as `x.listFiles()` returns null if `x` is not a folder). 
Therefore the code will reach the bottom line and each file will be deleted.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Does this mean it returns null  back to the for loop call deleteDirectory(1stFile) for the for loop to continue and keep going?  In this case it would be file 2, then 3 etc? all the way up to 5000? One more thing this code does not actually delete the folder correct? I would still need to delete that

Comment: It deletes the actual folder. It deletes all of its contents (that happens in the for loop) then when that for loop is complete, which means the contents have all been deleted the final line gets run deleting the folder itself.